# AWS Elasticsearch as eventstore

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, event-stream

I am planning to use AWS Elasticsearch as an eventstore DB. Mostly the events would be something like an instance ID and an event of login/logout etc. In this scenario the instance ID pretty much remains the same but events would keep on updating along with the timestamp of such events.

Was wondering if anybody has an experience with Elastic for such a scenario and any pointers on how best to inject such data into ES indices ?

Answer (score 1):

Its a very common use of Elasticsearch and a lot of companies uses Elasticsearch to store/track the various events of the system for example user-clicks/user activity on the website which seems to closely related to your use-case.

You can easily use elasticsearch for this use case and for system generated metrics/events or even for these metrics, which normally initially logged on files in raw format and later on refined and stored in Elasticsearch, you can use the [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat) which is very easy to configure and has [several integration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-modules.html) with various popular system, otherwise you can simply configure it according to your need.